# Prove inequality $\sum_{k = 1}^n x_k y_k \ge \sum_{k = 1}^n u_kv_k$, where $u, v $- ordered $x$ and $y$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, optimization

Given two sequences of numbers $-$ $x = \{x_i\}_{i = 1}^n$ and $y =\{y_i\}_{i = 1}^n$.

We construct sequence $u = \{u_i\}_{i = 1}^n$, which is $x$, but ordered in non-increasing ($u_1 \ge u_2 \ge ... \ge u_n,$ exist a bijection $\sigma:\{1,2,⋯,n\}\rightarrow\{1,2,⋯,n\}$ satisfying $x_{σ(i)}=u_i \; \forall i \in\{1,2,⋯,n\})$ and sequence $v =\{v_i\}_{i = 1}^n$, which is $y$, but ordered in non-decreasing.

I need to show 
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n x_k y_k \ge \sum_{k = 1}^n u_kv_k.$$
How can i begin? Probably i can use Jensen inequality some way?

Comment: Are you aware of what this inequality is called? If you know Jensen's, you should have seen this before. [This is the inequality.](https://brilliant.org/wiki/rearrangement-inequality/)

Comment: so it is Rearrangment Inequality. But it seems that all proofs are on sequence-language. I wonder maybe there is some smooth proof inequality-way? Or there is none?

Comment: I think the notation is not accurate. $x_i = u_i$ implies that the sequnece is not rearranged. you can write as: there exist a bijection $\sigma \colon \{1, 2, \cdots, n\} \to \{1, 2, \cdots, n\}$ satisfying $x_{\sigma(i)} = u_i$ for all $i \in \{1, 2, \cdots, n\}$.

Comment: @dust05, yes, thanks, it is more accurate.